# Identify rows with two values in same column

Tags: r

I have got a dataset that looks like this:

```
sample <- c("sample1", "sample1", "sample2", "sample2", "sample3", "sample3", "sample4", "sample4")
value1<- c(1, 5, 7, NA, NA, 3, 2, 1)
type <- c("x", "x", "y", "y", "x", "y", NA, NA)
myinput <- data.frame(sample, value1, type)

> myinput
   sample value1 type
1 sample1      1    x
2 sample1      5    x
3 sample2      7    y
4 sample2     NA    y
5 sample3     NA    x
6 sample3      3    y
7 sample4      2 <NA>
8 sample4      1 <NA>
```

I would like to label the rows by individual `samples`, based on how many different values are present in the `type` column, as follows:

- One value (only `x` OR `y`, but not both) -> `single`
- Two values (`x` AND `y`, but NOT `NA`) -> `double`
- `NA` values -> `none`

The dataset doesn't contain any samples with `x`/`y` AND `NA`.

Desired output:

```
   sample value1 type label
1 sample1      1    x single
2 sample1      5    x single
3 sample2      7    y single
4 sample2     NA    y single
5 sample3     NA    x double
6 sample3      3    y double
7 sample4      2 <NA>   none
8 sample4      1 <NA>   none
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With nested `ifelse`, one could do:

```r
library(dplyr)
myinput |> 
  mutate(number = ifelse(anyNA(type), "none", 
                         ifelse(all(sort(unique(type)) == c("x", "y")), "double", 
                                "single")),
         .by = sample)

#    sample value1 type number
# 1 sample1      1    x single
# 2 sample1      5    x single
# 3 sample2      7    y single
# 4 sample2     NA    y single
# 5 sample3     NA    x double
# 6 sample3      3    y double
# 7 sample4      2 <NA>   none
# 8 sample4      1 <NA>   none
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the code with `ave` like below

```
transform(
    myinput,
    label = c("single","double","none")[match(ave(match(type,c("x","y")), sample,FUN = var)==0,c(TRUE,FALSE,NA))]
)
```

which gives

```
   sample value1 type  label
1 sample1      1    x single
2 sample1      5    x single
3 sample2      7    y single
4 sample2     NA    y single
5 sample3     NA    x double
6 sample3      3    y double
7 sample4      2 <NA>   none
8 sample4      1 <NA>   none
```

Answer (score 3):

Another `ave`

```
c("none","single","double")[
  as.integer(
    ave(
      myinput$type,
      myinput$sample,
      FUN=function(x){length(unique(na.omit(x)))}
    )
  )+1
]

[1] "single" "single" "single" "single" "double" "double" "none"   "none"
```

Comment: Could avoid integer conversion by changing function to: `\(x) c("none","single","double")[length(na.omit(unique(x))) + 1L]`